# Many to Many Relationships in Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

Hey,
I've got a bit of a problem right now trying to figure out how to resolve a specific many to many model in Mongo.

I have an event scheduling system for the CRM I am building that allows events to be assigned to both users and teams. These events are particular to each lead.

So for example, I have a call at 5:00pm Thursday with Jimmy Dolittle. My sales team also has a call Thursday at 7:00am with Bob Jones.

If this were SQL, I would just create a leads table, events table, users table, and teams table. I was thinking about putting the events in the users collection and in the teams collection but then the problem arises when I have a list of leads and want to display the callback date next to each lead. Referencing like that in Mongo is going to be sloooow with a list of 500 leads.

I was also thinking about storing the events in the leads collection, but that would mean I would have to do the same sort of search for leads with events assigned to a particular user or team (there might be 500,000 leads in the database but only 500 have events for a particular user.

Comment: SQL databases are called **relational** database management systems for a reason. If you want relations, use a relational system.

Comment: someone has to have encountered a similar scenario before though

Comment: I'm sure they have. I suspect such an encounter spurred the development of the first relational database. If you are using MongoDB because it's cool and trendy instead of because it's the right solution for your needs, **stop**.

Comment: I'm currently using mysql, and for everything else other than user management and event scheduling..structureless collections makes WAAAAYYY more sense and work great. I'm in the process of migrating over to Mongo and this is the last puzzle piece.

Comment: Nothing says you can't use both and take advantage of the benefits of both types of system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of relationship is just going to be a problem in Mongo. In that situation, I would probably write a function for connecting those objects at the application level. Whenever a connection is made, save the relationship in both objects. Then you can search either direction with ease. You'll have redundant data and that causes a risk of getting them out of sync, but that's the price you have to pay with a non-relational structure. Your updates won't be as fast since you'll have to update two docs, but your selects should be speedy.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Suggests a good idea would be to solve this at the app level.

What i'd do here is create a new collection 'Events' then store an array of _id's of related events inside the user and team objects from here it will be super fast to do a look up. It may mean a lot more queries but queries on the _id field alone are highly optimised and not very resource intensive (unless you have millions of events per user) so if a team has the app up they can see their events and if a user has theirs up they can see their events.

Also i recommend storing back links to the user and team _id's in the event object. Yes this is redundant data but its only a reference and if managed properly at the app level should keep the schema nice and tidy.

Best of Luck.